# How can I 302 redirect all pages of a subdomain to the subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Here is my question:
Say I have a sub-domain.domainXXZ.com, and the subdomain has many pages, such as

```
http:// sub-domain.domainXXZ.com/ppph.html
http:// sub-domain.domainXXZ.com/ssph.html
http:// sub-domain.domainXXZ.com/ppp1.html
http:// sub-domain.domainXXZ.com/ppp2.html
...
http:// sub-domain.domainXXZ.com/pppn.html
```

I want to 302 redirect all pages of this subdomain to `http:// sub-domain.domainXXZ.com`.

How to write the rules in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you want to forward pages from subdomain1.domain.com to subdomain2.domain.com? If so,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain2.domainXXZ.com/$1 [R]
```

Otherwise, if you meant to redirect all pages to the root directory,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(A-Za-z0-9\.)*$ http://subdomain.domainXXZ.com/ [R]
```

should work (haven't tested).

Comment: Tom Marthenal, thank you for you fast reply, and I am sorry for my poor English, I am not a native English speaker. I do not mean to forward pages from subdomain1.domain.com to subdomain2.domain.com. I want to redirect all pages of subdomain1.domain.com to subdomain1.domain.com

Comment: The second example should work. I haven't tested it, though, so if it doesn't let me know and I'll fix it.